# Можно ли как-то ограничить background linear-gradient у заголовка?

Tags: css, background, linear-gradient

Такая ситуация: есть **h1** и к нему добавлено свойство **background** со значением **linear-gradient**, а ещё **у заголовка есть псевдоэлемент after**, который также имеет это свойство.

В общем, хочу узнать: **существует ли способ задать лимит для фона кнопки как это показано на скрине?**

```css
.main-menu-section h1 {
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 45, 154, 1), #1f5fc7);
    border-radius: 10px 5px;
    font-weight: 700;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

.main-menu-section h1::after {
    /* position: absolute; */
    content: "БУКМЕКЕРОВ";
    top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-menu-section">
<h1>ТОП-5</h1>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```css
   .main-menu-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-menu-section h1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px 0 10px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 45, 154, 1), #1f5fc7);
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
}

.main-menu-section h1::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  content: "БУКМЕКЕРОВ";
  background: inherit;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-menu-section">
<h1>ТОП-5</h1>
</div>
```

PS Гемблинг - это зло, но клоакинг - это ещё большее зло.

Comment: Похоже, вы неправильно поняли суть вопроса..)
Желаемый результат должен получиться таким, как на скрине (я показал его чёрной обводкой)

А я и не делал клоаку :) всего лишь простецкий сайт-агрегатор различных БК с рефками (ну уж без этого никак - кушать всем хочется))

Comment: заменил код. Если ещё какие завитушки будут нужны, то это уже используй clip-path и помощь дизайнера, или того кто умеет в svg